# print all files in a folder

Tags: xargs, printf

let's say `ls` retunrs `file1 file2 dir1 dire2 ...`, I want to print `you have file1 file2 dir1 dire2 ... in currnent folder`.

How can I do that?
`ls | xargs -i echo 'you have {} in current folder'` prints

```
you have file1 in current folder
you have file2 in current folder
you have dir1 in current folder
you have dir2 in current folder
you have xxx in current folder
```

also, I have tried 
`ls |xargs printf 'you have %s %s %s %s in current folder'`
but couldn't make it work.  as the number of files is indefinite. what is the right syntax for `printf` in this case?

`ls | xargs printf 'you have $@ in current folder'` is the closest I can get, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The following will work but probably has some negative security implications:

```
echo "You have" * "in current folder"
```

IMO a better way, but requiring two lines would be:

```
files=(*)
echo "You have ${files[@]} in curent folder"
```

---

With printf:

```
files=(*)
printf '%s ' "You have ${files[@]} in current folder"
```

Comment: I think `${files[*]}` should be prefered over `${files[@]}`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3355375/2779871

Comment: @JulesRandolph:  Negative, `@` should be used over `*` in almost every instance, `*` is delimited by your `IFS` which could cause undesirable results especially in this instance.  OP wants the files printed on a single line so if `IFS` was set to `\n` then it would not provide the output he wants...or if `IFS` was set to basically anything but the default...

Comment: nice.... thanks!!  how to concatenate indefinite parameters passed in?
printf 'you have passed in %s %s %s ??.... paramters'

Comment: @BoChen This will concatenate all of the files regardless of how many there are.

Comment: @Jesse_b yeah I've already tried it out. your solution works well. I'm asking the `printf` questions because I'm interested to know that as well..

Comment: @Jesse_b You are right !

Comment: @Jesse_b thanks again for your answer. why does `ls | xargs printf 'you have $@ in current folder' ` not work?

Comment: @BoChen It "works", it just doesn't do what you think it should do. Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Comment: @Jesse_b However, here are some arguments against it: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2145

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth:

```
echo You have $(ls) in the current folder
```

Comment: thanks. works well!  Can you help answer my second question as well ? i.e. `ls |xargs printf 'you have %s %s %s %s in current folder'` way, how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think Jesse_b's solution is the best, but if you want something like `xargs` you can use GNU Parallel:

```
ls | parallel --xargs echo you have {} in current folder
```